# [MongoDB]:Can I deploy multiple mongod instance in a server for production environment?

Tags: mongodb

If I deploy multiple mongod instance in a server? what are the benefits and risks? if my cpu has 8 cores, could such a deployment take advantage of the multi-core?

Comment: This setup is mentioned in the following blog post http://blog.schmichael.com/2011/11/05/failing-with-mongodb/ but it looks like they moved out of MongoDB altogether instead.

Comment: Yes you can but there are many many bad aspects of doing such a thing...like memory management for one and no it won't take advantage of multi cpu unless you virtualise the instances mongod is running on and physically tell the virtualisation software to use that core.